# kdialog --passivepopup notification only shows up after second message

Tags: ubuntu, kde, notifications, kde-4

On an up to date Kubuntu precise, my notifications will only pop up after the second one. I'm using:

```
kdialog --title "foo" --passivepopup "bar"
```

The first one is shown in the system tray only – the dialog popups only appear after more invocations.

How to fix this?

```
$ uname -a
Linux susi 3.2.0-39-generic-pae #62-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 27 22:25:11 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
$ lsb_release -a  
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise
```

Comment: If you're not widely distributing this, try coding it with yad instead of kdialog. yad has many great features including support for notify. It is being actively developed and supported. https://code.google.com/p/yad/

Comment: I'll take a look at it, thanks! Still, I think that this should work out of the box with kdialog.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like it should work. My only point is that with yad, you have an active developer and community to talk to if it doesn't perform as desired.